# stopping threads

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a winform app that contains a form1 and the program.cs file. in program.cs i initialize form1 and besides that, i have a server included. My question is : how can i stop the threads when i close the form? here is part of my program.cs file :

```
public void start()
        {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }


        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("in thread");
            this.tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                //blocks until a client has connected to the server
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                //create a thread to handle communication 
                //with connected client
                sThread a = new sThread(form1, listaThreads);
                listaThreads.Add(a);
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(a.HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can call `Close()` of the `TcpListener` from a different thread.**

`TcpListener.Close()` will simply call `Socket.Close()` and that is thread safe.

I'm not sure how the `AcceptTcpClient` reacts, but you'll have to check that. At least it will stop your listening thread in a normal way.

So, you do:

```
tcpListener.Close();
listenThread.Join();
```

That will nicely close your thread.

Comment: tcpListener.Close(); does not exist. i found tcpListener.Close(); the AcceptTcpClient gives the following error : A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall

Comment: I believe that the `WSACancelBlockingCall` is the correct way of terminating the blocking call here. You should treat that exception as the trigger to close the thread. I was first going to answer with the `BeginAcceptTcpClient`, but this is the way you terminate the thread when you're not using the asynchronous versions of the calls.

Comment: i've resolved it : using this code : try
                {
                    client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                }
                catch
                {
                break;
                }

Comment: Yep, that's how you do it. Well, one thing: please change your catch into `catch (WSACancelBlockingCall)`. That way, you are actually checking for this specific case and you'll still see other errors.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than actively aborting them you should signal to them that they should stop and allow them to stop in their own time. If you are using any [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)s you can use the [`CancelAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx) method. For the threads created manually like in your example you can use a  boolean flag (with appropriate synchronization) that the thread must occasionally check. When your program is about to close set the flag. Avoid calling blocking methods in your threads - use the asynchronous methods instead such as [`BeginAcceptTcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx) instead of `AcceptTcpClient`.

If you are using (or can upgrade to) .NET 4 then you should also consider using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) where tasks are [cancellable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx).

Comment: I think is fairly obvious from the existing code :) Maybe Alexnadru can confirm it.

Comment: @Liviu M.: I admit you're *probably* right, but I thought I'd mention it anyway just in case. :) And partially to raise awareness of this useful class.

Comment: @Mark, IMO, from code sample, OP may not need synchronized flag - worker threads can exit when flag become true (w/o using locks). Of course, synchronization is must in many (other) cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the method that runs async you should check for a boolean flag say `cancel` that you set to true from outside when you want to stop the thread.

```
public bool cancel = false;

public void MethodRuningOnThread()
{
   while(!cancel)
   {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

It is not recommended to use the `Thread.Abort()` method.

Comment: i agree with you, but i am afraid that before i get to change that flag, my program will be blocked in the sr.readLine()